# Korean version of Reddit: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403

Tags: html, django, google-chrome, web-scraping

I had so much fun with *MSOutlookit* (a website basically rekinning Reddit into an Outlook interface). So I’m building a Korean version of it, using their codes (https://github.com/attaxia/MSOutlookit).

Im basically scrapping posts from a website called *DCInside* (a Reddit-like website popular in Korea)

**Here is the problem.** An image scrapped from a post in this website is only shown on my website when *Chrome Developer Mode* is enabled. When the mode isn’t turned on, I get 403 error.

At first, i thought it was a size problem of img on css. But doesnt seem to solve the issue.

***Here is the code i used***

```
<div class="crawl_contents">
        {{ data.content|safe }}
      </div>
```

Please help me guys!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you actually tryin to help! I really didnt expect anyone to read this post. As you may already guess from my post, Im quite new with this field. So it means a lot to me if you can tell me what details i need to provide for you!